# Detecting wide screen aspect ratio

Tags: c, aspect-ratio

This code is trying to work out the best window size for a users monitor size. To do this I'm trying to detect the aspect ratio of the users monitor.

This method that I'm using works properly for 4:3, 16:9, 16:10 resolutions but it fails (goes to the default case) for 21:9 resolutions because `2560 * 21 != 1920 * 9`. How do you properly detect aspect ration on a wide screen aspect ratio?

`dm.w` and `dm.h` are the width and height of the current resolution

```
if( dm.h * 4 == dm.w * 3 ) { // 4:3
    screen_width = 1024;
    screen_height = 768;
} else if( dm.h * 16 == dm.w * 9 ) { // 16:9
    screen_width = 1366;
    screen_height = 768;
} else if( dm.h * 16 == dm.w * 10 ) { // 16:10
    screen_width = 1440;
    screen_height = 900;
} else if( dm.h * 21 == dm.w * 9 ) { // 21:9
    screen_width = 1920;
    screen_height = 720;
} else {
    Printf( "Unknown aspect ratio. Defaulting to 1024x768\n" );
    screen_width = 1024;
    screen_height = 768;
}
```

Comment: You *do* know there are many more possible resolutions? How about 1280x800 for example? Or the very common 1920x1080? Or the (unfortunately uncommon) 1920x1200? Or how about modern 27 or 30 (or larger) inch displays with larger resolutions?

Comment: Do you mean that those resolutions won't be properly detected with this?

Comment: You should not use the aspect ratio to detect resolution. Instead each operating system already have functions to get the actual resolution, and all supported resolutions as well. If you really want the aspect ratio, it's easy to calculate once you have the resolution.

Comment: For Windows, you might want to read about [`EnumDisplaySettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162611%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm not trying to use the aspect ratio to detect resolution. I'm trying to detect the aspect ratio so that I can choose the best size for my window. I only want to support a few different window sizes so that the 2d graphics in my game don't get stretched at resolutions that I don't support.

Comment: Then get the current resolution, calculate the aspect ratio from that, and set your own resolution.

Comment: That's what my question is about. It doesn't calculate the aspect ratio correctly for 21:9 resolutions

Comment: The resolution 2560x1920 is 4:3, not 21:9. For what resolution you think you should get 21:9 aspect ratio?

Comment: What are the values of dm.h and dm.w in the case where your detection fails ?

Comment: compare against some epsilon values

Answer (score 0):

The width and height of the current resolution tells you nothing about monitor aspect ratio. For example, 3 monitors of different sizes (e.g. 4:3, 16:10 and 16:12) can all be using 1024*768.

To get the actual aspect ratio you need information from the monitor itself. Most monitors support something called EDID (Extended Display Identification Data) which includes the monitor's active display area width and height in mm.

Of course you wouldn't want to extract this information from the raw EDID data itself - you'd want an API and/or library that provides information originally obtained from EDID. I don't know which OS you're using; but wouldn't be surprised if there were libraries and/or APIs available. Also don't be surprised if things like multiple monitors complicate things for you (e.g. I'm using 2 monitors that are different sizes).